# Pass a method to another method

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to be able to specify a method in another method.

Something like

```
public class Binder
{
    public void Bind(whatShouldIWriteHere?)
    {
        // do stuff with the MethodInfo
    }
}
```

so that I can do:

```
public class A
{
    public void DoIt(string tmp)
    {
    }
}

var binder = new Binder()
binder.Bind<A>(x => x.DoIt);
```

Instead of:

```
var method = typeof(A).GetMethod("DoIt");
binder.Bind(method);
```

Is that possible? :)

Comment: Do you want a MethodInfo or a delegate?

Comment: I want a method info. But without having to use strings.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the method as a delegate and use the Delegate.Method property.

In your case Binder.Bind would be like:

```
public void Bind(Delegate del)
{
    var info = del.Method;
    //Add your logic here.
}
```

And to pass a method to it:

```
var binder = new Binder();
var instance = new A();
binder.Bind(new Action<string>(instance.DoIt))
```

Comment: Rather than passing `Delegate` it's probably better to just accept a particular type of delegate, in this case `Action` seems appropriate.

Comment: In this case it would be `Action<string>` actually, and I thought that it would be too restrictive.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be `Action<string>`, because there is nothing to pass into the method.  He should create a method with no arguments and no return value that just calls `DoIt` with whatever parameter should be used.  The most convenient way to do that is with a lambda.  If there really is a string that needs to be passed, then using `Delegate` would not only be a bad idea, but wouldn't be an option, and you would *need* to pass in a specific type, such as `Action<string>`.

Comment: I think Action exists under a not generic form.

Comment: The problem is that the delegate could be anything. So it's just slightly better than passing a string.